# iOS 16.0 - PH Picker issue con config selection = .people

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy teniendo problemas con `PHPickerViewController` en iOS 16.0 con PHPickerConfiguration `config.selection = .people`.
Se muestra el siguiente error: "Unable to Load Photos" en la pantalla. Xcode: 14.0.1

```
import UIKit
import PhotosUI

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          showPicker()
     }

    private func showPicker() {
       var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
       config.filter = .images
       config.selection = .people
       config.selectionLimit = 10
       let vc = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
       vc.delegate = self
       self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {

    }
}
```

Console log:

```
[Picker] Showing picker unavailable UI (reason: crashed) with error: (null)
viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

La pregunta concreta es: alguien pasó por esto? existe una solución ?

Comment: Puedes agregar en la pregunta el código en donde delegas el objeto y las funciones de `PHPickerViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La documentación de Apple no sabe ser muy detallada pero en este caso, no tiene ninguna información acerca de `.people`.

Dentro de `PhotosUI` -> `PHPickerConfiguration` en Xcode 14.0.1 encuentras esto:

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
    public enum Selection {

        /// Uses the default selection behavior.
        case `default`

        /// Uses the selection order made by the user. Selected assets are numbered.
        case ordered

        @available(iOS 16.0, *)
        case people

        /// Returns a Boolean value indicating whether two values are equal.
        ///
        /// Equality is the inverse of inequality. For any values `a` and `b`,
        /// `a == b` implies that `a != b` is `false`.
        ///
        /// - Parameters:
        ///   - lhs: A value to compare.
        ///   - rhs: Another value to compare.
        public static func == (a: PHPickerConfiguration.Selection, b: PHPickerConfiguration.Selection) -> Bool
```

Sorprendentemente `people` no tiene ningún comentario, solo que es disponible en iOS 16.

De igual manera si haces un debug con un punto de interrupción en la línea de tu código `vc.delegate = self`, al inspeccionar la configuración asignada muestra lo siguiente:

1. `config.selection = .default`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. `config.selection = .ordered`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. `config.selection = .people`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que resulta extraño es que siguiendo la lógica del `enum`, las opciones siguen un orden

```
.default //0
.ordered //1
.people//2
```

Por lo que `.people` debería ser 2 pero en las imágenes adjuntas muestra -1 y por eso no muestra las fotos y da el warning en la zona de debug.

Podría ser que `.people` aún no esté implementado pero sería una opinión. Este es el link de la documentación de Apple del [PHPickerConfigurationSelection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerconfiguration/selection)